# Improving a regex for the hashtag to generate a link

Tags: regex, regexp-replace

I'm using this Regular Expression

```
(^|\s)(#\w+)
```

> ```
> To take this -> #test
>
> #test <- to take this
>
> to take this #test another word
>
> to take this #Mest another word
>
> To don't take this -> l'#09
>
> to don't take this -> &#187; or &#39;
> ```

But I have a problem during the substitution.

I use this

```
$1<a href="/hash/$2" class='hash_tag'>$2</a>
```

But in this way I have the # also in the href.

For example

```
Take this <a href="/hash/#test" class='hash_tag'>test</a>
```

While, I have to obtain this

```
Take this <a href="/hash/test" class='hash_tag'>#test</a>
```

Any tips?

Do I need a third group? How to do?

Can I improve it?

https://regex101.com/r/6C1VDU/1

Comment: Why using once `"` and another time `'` for HTML attributes?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Adding a third group is easy:

```
(^|\s)(#(\w+))
|__1_|| |   ||
      | |_3_||
      |____2_|
```

Replace with

```
$1<a href="/hash/$3" class='hash_tag'>$2</a>
```

See [proof](https://regex101.com/r/Bt0fvI/1).

Comment: oh, very good. Another question. If I can not add an $1 out of the tag <a>, how can I edit the regex?

Comment: @J.Luca  Try `(?<=^|\s)(#(\w+))`  and use `<a href="/hash/$2" class='hash_tag'>$1</a>` to replace.

Answer (score 0):

You need to modify the regex and replacement:

**Regex**: `(^|\s)#(\w+)` 
**Replacement**: `$1<a href="/hash/$2" class='hash_tag'>#$2</a>`

See the [regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/GX70Kl/1/).

So, the `#` is left out of capturing group #2, and you only add it where you need in the replacement pattern.